# textbox text trim allow 1 blankspace asp net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, trim

I have a textbox that I want to allow 1 blank space. So right now, the trim method does not allow it, but is there anyway to allow 1 blank space?

C#:

```
bool before = txtSearchFor.Text.StartsWith(" ");
bool after = txtSearchFor.Text.EndsWith(" ");
string newText = before && after
                 ? txtSearchFor.Text.Trim() + " "
                 : before ? " " + txtSearchFor.Text.TrimStart() : after ? txtSearchFor.Text.TrimEnd() + " " : txtSearchFor.Text;

var contacts = SearchNRender(ExtCatIdentifier.All.ToString(), txtSearchFor.Text = newText);
var searchFormat = string.Format("[ {0} ]", txtSearchFor.Text);
```

Comment: allow 1 blank space at which side? left or right or any of them?

Comment: Any of them, does not matter, as long as it's only 1 blank space, not more.

Comment: Just don't use the `Text.Trim()`, check is it fulfil your requirement in `OnTextChanged`, or you have other purpose?

Comment: Does it **need** to have a space? What if there is a space at both ends?

Comment: A blank space is a wildcard search on my application, that's why I need to allow it to happen.

Comment: Ok, what if there are spaces at the beginning and end of the string? Which one is more important? 1 space in total or consecutive?

Comment: Post please, cant see on comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool before = txtSearchFor.Text.StartsWith(" ");
bool after  = txtSearchFor.Text.EndsWith(" ");
string newText = before && after 
                 ? txtSearchFor.Text.Trim() + " " 
                 : before ? " " + txtSearchFor.Text.TrimStart() : after ? txtSearchFor.Text.TrimEnd() + " " : txtSearchFor.Text;

txtSearchFor.Text = newText;
```

Comment: With this code, I can input as many blankspaces as I want, I want it to be maximum of 1 blank space.

Comment: @Malphai Well maybe you could provide a couple of examples or use-cases.

Comment: No, for some reason, it still takes endless blankspaces.

Comment: I have this code just one line after this Trim, does it affect anything? "var searchFormat = string.Format("[ {0} ]", txtSearchFor.Text);"

Comment: If I just put 10 blank spaces without anything else, it still accepts it.

Comment: Yes that's right, but I want the user to get no search hit if there is more than 1 blank space, I want it to be trimmed.

Answer (score -1):

use this simple code:

```
string t = txtSearchFor.Text;

if (t.StartsWith(" ")) //starts is blank, end may be blank or not
    t = " " + t.Trim(); 
else if (t.EndsWith(" ")) //only end is blank
    t = t.TrimEnd() + " ";

txtSearchFor.Text = t;


//Outputs:
// "    abc def   " => " abc def"
// "abcd def      " => "abc def "
// "    abc def" => " abc def"
```

Comment: He doesn't what to trim one space but trim **all but one** spaces. It also doesn't take into account that there might be spaces at both ends.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer please see my update and revise your vote if possible

Comment: It's still wrong (and the question changed again). Despite this I'll retract my downvote because that's not entirely your fault. A bit of advice: As tempting as it may be to try and answer a (seemingly easy) low quality question as this before anyone else, ask for clarifications and a [mcve] to make sure you know all the details first.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer you are right as it was not so clear at first what he wants to do... but whats wrong with this code now?

Comment: He provided some additional information as a comment on Tim's answer: *"I want the user to get no search hit if there is more than 1 blank space, I want it to be trimmed."*. There are a couple of other statements spread all over the place but I don't really feel like attempting to decode what the actual question was in the end - I'd have to piece together a timeline ... Well anyway, there is already an accepted answer so OP has probably moved on and will never return. I suggest we do the same.